# LoadRunner 12.50 recording issue

Tags: internet-explorer, loadrunner

Running 12.50 in a VM under Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter with 6gb RAM. Since upgrading from 12.02 to 12.50 (5 days ago)  I am unable to get anything to record in the new installation. Using WEB/HTTP protocol, once recorder starts, the IE browser just returns "This page cant be displayed" error. On clicking 'Fix Connection Problems' in the browser display, it just says there are no connection issues. No actual errors are logged in the log file so I have no idea where LR has an issue.

Running scripts that worked under 12.02, I got 404 not found returned, but after faffing around with the proxy settings and set the browser emulation to IE 10 it seemed to fix the re running issues.

Wierd thing is I can connect to the affected URL's outside LoadRunner using IE,  so IE seems to work OK but wont connect in record mode.

Update : Set IE version 11 in runtime settings as per LR installation prerequisites. For some reason, was set to 10 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an SSL handshake failure. You need to analyze the recording log of your script: it might contain some clues of what happens during recording.

Here's a good [article](http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/The-Port-Mapping-dialog-one-dialog-that-does-it-all/ba-p/6357353#.VxCwWfmLSCp) explaining how to deal with SSL recording issues by means of the Port Mapping. Also check this [one](http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/5-tips-to-solve-the-most-common-problems-seen-in-Web-recording/ba-p/6357387#.VxCw__mLSCp) about general Web Protocol recording issues.

Comment: Thanks - it was SSL mismatch. Even HP techies missed this one as I had a fault ticket raised and sent a LRDetect dump to them. 12.50 apparently defaults to SSL 3.0 - some servers in our infrastructure use TLS1.1 and caused havoc with both recording and playback.

Answer (score 0):

Performance testing tools + clock float inside of virtual machines = Bad Magic